# Difficulties creating a boxplot based on survey data

Tags: r, ggplot2, survey

I have difficulties with creating a boxplote based on a survey from school about collecting cardboard. about 30 people participated. The values in my excel file range from 0 to over 1'000 Grams.
When i try this following code, a lot of the data from d.Daten_Agg are "NA". (i want to sort it by the postal code (plz) and the values of all the data points from each town)

```
d.Daten_Agg <- aggregate(list(kk_agg = d.Daten$k_kehrricht),
                            list(plz = d.Daten$plz),
                            function(x) round(sd(x, na.rm = TRUE), 1))
d.Daten_Agg

ggplot(d.Daten_Agg, aes(y=d.Daten_Agg)) + 
  stat_boxplot(geom="errorbar", width=0.5)+
  geom_boxplot(fill="darkorchid3", outlier.color="darkorchid3", outlier.size=3, outlier.shape=8, width = 1) +
  ylab("Karton Kehrricht [kg]")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, margin = margin(t = 10), size = 12, vjust=2, face = "bold")) +
  xlab("alle Daten")+
  scale_x_discrete()
```

I also get this error message:

```
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of
type <data.frame>. Defaulting to continuous.
Error in `stat_boxplot()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `check_aesthetics()`:
! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as
  the data (21)
✖ Fix the following mappings: `y`
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Do you see a mistake i could've made? I'm also not sure why a lot of the data points at d.Daten_Agg are suddenly of no value ("NA").

I tried to use kk_agg instead of d.Daten_Agg in the ggplot, but i got another error message:

```
Error in ggplot(kk_agg, aes(y = kk_agg)) : object 'kk_agg' not found
```

Answer (score 1):

The first argument of `ggplot()` is the `data`set and the second is the `mapping` where you specify which columns of the data you want to map on which aesthetic via `aes()`, i.e. use `ggplot(d.Daten_Agg, aes(y = kk_agg))` to tell ggplot that your dataset is called `d.Daten_Agg` and that you want to map the column `kk_agg` on `y`.

Using a minimal reproducible example based on `mtcars`:

```r
d.Daten <- mtcars[c("mpg", "cyl")]
names(d.Daten) <- c("k_kehrricht", "plz")

d.Daten_Agg <- aggregate(
  list(kk_agg = d.Daten$k_kehrricht),
  list(plz = d.Daten$plz),
  function(x) round(sd(x, na.rm = TRUE), 1)
)
d.Daten_Agg
#>   plz kk_agg
#> 1   4    4.5
#> 2   6    1.5
#> 3   8    2.6

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(d.Daten_Agg, aes(y = kk_agg)) +
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", width = 0.5) +
  geom_boxplot(
    fill = "darkorchid3", outlier.color = "darkorchid3",
    outlier.size = 3, outlier.shape = 8, width = 1
  ) +
  ylab("Karton Kehrricht [kg]") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(
    hjust = 0.5, margin = margin(t = 10),
    size = 12, vjust = 2, face = "bold"
  )) +
  xlab("alle Daten") +
  scale_x_discrete()
```

[image]